# Zabbix monitoring web server afther 2 or 3 check

Tags: zabbix

I have a web server and I set up monitoring from zabbix access to site. For example access to https://server/test/

First I set up Web scenarios where I checked access to a site then I created Trigger

Problem expression:
`{server:web.test.fail[server/test].last()}<>0`

Recovery expression
`{server:web.test.fail[server/test].last()}=0`

It works fine but I want so that the trigger turn on after two or three check but now trigger turn on after one check.

How to set up quantity of attempts in the triger?

Answer (score 0):

I decided the probrem

Problem expression: {server:web.test.fail[server/test].min(#3)}>0

Recovery expression {server:web.test.fail[server/test].max(#1)}=0